# How to call user input from JSP file into Java file

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm writing a program using JSP. I have a .java file containing a few methods, and I have a .jsp file which contains the following, in addition to a few javascript methods:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div id="nameDiv"></div>
<div id="nameInput">
    <input type="text" name="nameOne" value="Enter a Name" onClick="if(this.value == 'Enter a Name'){this.value = '';}" /> 
    <input type="text" name="nameTwo" value="Enter a Name" onClick="if(this.value == 'Enter a Name'){this.value = '';}" /> 
    <input type="text" name="nameThree" value="Enter a Name" onClick="if(this.value == 'Enter a Name'){this.value = '';}" /> 
    <input type="button" name="btnUpdate" value="Update Name" />
</div>
```

My question is: how can I call the user input from these textboxes, in a java file? Or better said, how can I call these inputs which are on a separate file (JSP), into my other separate java file and use the value that the user input in the textbox?

Comment: Use a [servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html). You can find more explanation and an example in [StackOverflow Servlet wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: You need to have your `inputs` inside a `form` with `action` pointing to the servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a servlet as your .java file,you can write your methods in this servlet class

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("nameOne");
        System.out.println("<form action='Myservlet.do' method='get'>");
        System.out.println("nameOne is " + name);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("nameThree");
        System.out.println("<form action='Myservlet.do' method='post'>");
        System.out.println("nameThree is " + name);
    }

}
```

and add this to your web.xml in WebContent/WEB-INF :

```
  <servlet>
    <!--whatever-->
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <!--the position of your own servlet-->
    <servlet-class>com.stackoverflowquizz.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <!--the same as the one in <servlet>-->
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <!--the action or the url that you can access this servlet-->
    <url-pattern>/Myservlet.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

use  `<form action = "xx" method="get/post"> <input type="submit">` in .jsp file to pass args to .java (servlet file)

```
    <form action="Myservlet.do" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="nameOne" value="Enter a Name" onClick="if(this.value == 'Enter a Name'){this.value = '';}" /> 
        <input type="text" name="nameTwo" value="Enter a Name" onClick="if(this.value == 'Enter a Name'){this.value = '';}" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form> 
    <form action="Myservlet.do" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nameThree" value="Enter a Name" onClick="if(this.value == 'Enter a Name'){this.value = '';}" /> 
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: can you please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139701/get-sqlexception-error-before-giving-the-user-input-in-jsp-page